# GitLab CI pipeline fialing with You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup a simple test stage for my GitLab Rails project with a simple build script (below) and I am getting an error:

```
bundler: failed to load command: rspec (/usr/local/bundle/bin/rspec)
Bundler::LockfileError: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:108:in `warn_for_outdated_bundler_version'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:95:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:72:in `new'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:72:in `initialize'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:200:in `new'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:200:in `to_definition'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:12:in `evaluate'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:33:in `build'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `definition'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:94:in `setup'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I am getting this error because they are using bundler `bundler-1.14.6` in their build and my Gemfile lock has been bundled with bundler 2.0.2. Is there a way to install the requried version of bundler on GitLab build?

This is my simple test job (taken from GitLab docs).

```
image: "ruby:2.4.0"

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev nodejs
  - ruby -v
  - which ruby
  - gem install bundler --no-document
  - bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}"

rspec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec
```

P.S. I've signed up to GitLab forum but they never activated my account that's why I am posting my question here.

Comment: adding `gem install bundler` as you have works for me.

Comment: adding `gem install bundler` worked for me-- thanks Kris!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using container registry, one possibility is to download docker image, use:

```
docker exec -itd container bash   # look it up, can't check syntax right now
```

and then inside container perform upgrade, next will be docker commit and tag(also look it up) and then update container registry on gitlab